# I am getting an error when trying to test my login using ARC. I'm using NodeJS, Express, JWT and AtlasMongoDB

Tags: node.js, authentication, advanced-rest-client

I'm trying to implement a login system using Nodejs, Express, JWT and MongoDB Atlas. The users are entered manually in the "data.js" file and are being shown in MongoDB Atlas but when I try to authenticate using the  Advanced REST client (ARC) I'm getting the following error:

```
{
"message": "Invalid email or password"
}
```

The following is the code:

**index.js:**

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import seedRouter from './routes/seedRoutes.js';
import productRouter from './routes/productRoutes.js';
import userRouter from './routes/userRoutes.js';

mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodb+srv://e-shopper123456:SimWkjLCoKjwCAlZ@e-shopper.ms9xt.mongodb.net/fsb?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Successfully connected to the database.');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });

const app = express();
const PORT = 3001;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/api/seed', seedRouter);
app.use('/api/products', productRouter);
app.use('/api/users', userRouter);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port: [${PORT}]`);
});
```

**data.js**

```
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

const data = {
  users: [
    {
      name: 'Matthew',
      email: 'matthew@test.com',
      password: bcrypt.hashSync('123456'),
    },
    {
      name: 'James',
      email: 'james@test.com',
      password: bcrypt.hashSync('123456'),
    },
  ],

  products: [
    {
      // _id: '1',
      slug: 'Playstation 5 Disc Version',
      name: 'Playstation 5 Disc Version',
      description: '',
      image: '/images/playstation5.jpeg',
      price: 499.99,
      countInStock: 0,
      rating: 4,
      numReviews: 30,
    },
    {
      // _id: '2',
      slug: 'Microsoft Xbox Series X Digital Edition 1TB',
      name: 'Microsoft Xbox Series X Digital Edition 1TB',
      description: 'This is a Microsoft console.',
      image: '/images/xboxseriesx.jpeg',
      price: 919,
      countInStock: 4,
      rating: 3.5,
      numReviews: 10,
    },
    {
      // _id: '3',
      slug: 'Call of Duty®: Vanguard - Standard Edition',
      name: 'Call of Duty®: Vanguard - Standard Edition',
      description:
        'The world continues to sink in the world’s largest and bloodiest conflict, but the seemingly desperate course of World War II is finally beginning to turn for the better. Now a handful of those chosen must rise to complete their task and change the face of war once and for all.',
      image: '/images/callofduty.jpeg',
      price: 59.99,
      countInStock: 5,
      rating: 4.5,
      numReviews: 12,
    },
    {
      // _id: '4',
      slug: 'Football Manager 2022',
      name: 'Football Manager 2022',
      description: '',
      image: '/images/footballmanager.jpeg',
      price: 54.99,
      countInStock: 8,
      rating: 5,
      numReviews: 15,
    },
    {
      // _id: '5',
      slug: 'World of Warcraft®: Shadowlands - Base Edition',
      name: 'World of Warcraft®: Shadowlands - Base Edition',
      description: '',
      image: '/images/worldofwarcraft.jpeg',
      price: 19.99,
      countInStock: 10,
      rating: 5,
      numReviews: 20,
    },
  ],
};

export default data;
```

**utils.js**

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export const generateToken = (user) => {
  return jwt.sign(
    {
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
    },
    'RANDOM_TOKEN',
    {
      expiresIn: '48h',
    }
  );
};
```

**models -> user.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Please provide an email'],
      match:
        /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/,
    },
    password: { type: String, required: [true, 'Please provide a password'] },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const user = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
export default user;
```

**routes -> userRoutes.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import User from '../models/user.js';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import { generateToken } from '../utils.js';

const userRouter = express.Router();

userRouter.post(
  '/login',

  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then((user) => {
      if (user) {
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.paswword, user.password)) {
          res.send({
            _id: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            token: generateToken(user),
          });
          return;
        }
      }
      res.status(401).send({ message: 'Invalid email or password' });
    });
  })
);

export default userRouter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a miss spell there: `req.body.paswword, user.password`.

By the way, you need to hash the password you received in the same way they are saved in database.

So you should do something like that:

```js
bcrypt.compareSync(bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password), user.password)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo.

As regards to the other part, you meant in the **userRoutes.js** like this right:
  
```expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then((user) => {
      if (user) {
        if (
          bcrypt.compareSync(bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password), user.password)
        ) {
          res.send({
            _id: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            token: generateToken(user),
          });
          return;
        }```

Ps. I'm still new to MERN.

Comment: You should not mix `await async` with `then`. The `await` is useless there. await version is:
```
const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
if (user) {...}

```

Comment: So when I would need to use the await async, I would use the if statement and not the ".then" correct?

I made some arrangements to the code, the user is getting authenticated even in frontend but somehow in the ARC client it still shows the following error even though the response is **200 OK**:

Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/tUG0BKzP

Also when I put in an incorrect e-mail, the backend crashes and I get the following error:

"**TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'password')**"

I tried searching on google on the above error but I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: `await/async` is an alternative to `then`

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne
You forgot to `.exec()`

Comment: I checked the link you sent above regarding the Model.findOne().exec. I implemented the .exec() in the code but still the same issue. Here is another pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/TvzKVYQw showing the error I'm getting in the ARC client and what I'm getting in the VSCode console, the console does show that the user authenticated.

Comment: I think you forget the `bodyParser` express middleware. Do you have some object into req.body ?

Comment: I managed to solve part of the issue I was getting with the ARC client, the issue which was causing the client to still give me the error, it was because of this line:

```
if (bcrypt.compareSync(bcrypt.Hash(req.body.password), user.password)) {
```

When I removed the bcrypt.Hash(), it works and I get the user info in the ARC client when I try to login. The only issue I have now, is that when I try to do an incorrect e-mail address, the backend does not respond but if I do an incorrect password, I get the error of invalid email and password as it should.

Comment: You forgot the body parser. So you probably get undefined as `req.body.password`

Comment: I don't know how to use the body parser. So I changed the code to include syntax errors when the username is entered incorrectly and also for the password, now the problem is that I cannot login even though if I do a console log and I click on Login it gets the user's data from the database. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the link to the new code: https://pastebin.com/qTXJ4eYD

Comment: Just want to point out that I managed to get the login system working.